# Односоставное определенно-личное предложение или предложение с однородными сказуемыми?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

*Вышел из комнаты(,) и поравнялся с дверным проемом.*

В этом предложении *вышел* и *поравнялся* являются сказуемыми, выраженными глаголом 1-го или 2-го лица ед.ч., то есть это определенно-личное, односоставное предложение, так? Насколько я знаю, в таких предложениях можно подставить местоимения 1-го, либо 2-го лица: "(Я) вышел из комнаты(,) и поравнялся с..." Могу ли я это воображаемое *Я* использовать в качестве подлежащего, и сказуемые *вышел* и *поравнялся*  определить как однородные?

А такое предложение: *Я вышел из комнаты(,) и поравнялся с дверным проемом.* Здесь однородные сказуемые *вышел* и *поравнялся* относятся к подлежащему *Я*, или же здесь ССП, где первая часть *Я вышел*, а вторая является односоставным, определенно-личным предложением?

Comment: Это не односоставное опр.-личное, это двусоставное неполное с однородными сказуемыми, потому что глагол по лицам изменяется только в настоящем и будущем времени, а здесь прошедшее - я вышел, ты вышел, он вышел - разницы нет, следовательно, лицо не может быть определено, только по контексту предыдущего предложения, а это - неполное двусоставное. Но запятой не было бы и между определённо-личными предложениями, там пунктуация как при однородных членах.

Comment: "Но запятой не было бы и между определённо-личными предложениями, там пунктуация как при однородных членах" - Вы имеете в виду мой первый пример? Потому что ниже М_Г привел мне пример сложного предложения, где обе части - определенно-личные предложения.

Comment: Кстати говоря: _Неполное предложение может быть восстановлено до полного (двусоставного или односоставного) по условиям контекста (например, ответная реплика в диалоге: У тебя завтра экзамен? - Завтра). Односоставное предложение не требует восстановления до двусоставного и является синтаксически законченным даже вне контекста._ - ответ справочной службы русского языка. А мое неполное предложение как-нибудь восстанавливается? Или "Грамота" привела лишь один из возможных примеров определения (отличия)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с более простого. **Я вышел из комнаты и поравнялся с дверным проемом.**
Я сделал два действия: (1) вышел, (2)поравнялся с проемом. Оба действия относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему **я**. Имеем подлежащее и однородные сказуемые. Запятая не нужна.

Далее. **Вышел из комнаты и поравнялся с дверным проемом.** Сдесь действует та же логика. Совершает оба действия одно и то же лицо, просто оно не упомянуто, но подразумевается. Сказуемые однородные, запятая не нужна.

Comment: Хорошо. А Вы можете привести пример, где каждая часть **сложного** предложения являлась бы односоставной, определенно-личной? Такие предложения вообще существуют?

Comment: Кричу, но не слышишь меня.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь я понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В рифму что-нибудь про нас после нас напишут